# for loop with a cursor only iterating once

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am running a search cursor with the code below (part of it) and my code is only yielding the first iteration. There isn't any selection on the FC prior.

Why is it stopping at the first iteration?

```
dict = {}
indicator1 = 0 
indicator2 = 0
fields = fields1+fields2
fields.append("OBJECTID")
cursor1 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, fields)
for row1 in cursor1:
    #find the WType that applies to each customer location
    for i in row1[:12]:
        if (i != None and i != 0 and i != 0.0):
            indicator1 = 1
            break
        else:
            continue
    for a in row1[12:-1]:
        if (a != None and a != 0 and a != 0.0):
            indicator2 = 1
            break
        else:
            continue
                            
    dict[row1[-1]] = [indicator1, indicator2]
    indicator1 = 0
    indicator2= 0
    print(f"This is the amount in dict {len(dict)}")
```

Comment: `else: continue` on the last statement of a `for` is a waste. But this is pure Python coding, not anything to do with ArcPy or the cursor. You're not using the `with` construct , and your code doesn't explicitly unlock the cursor with a `del`, which is a major GIS-related flaw.

Comment: Noted on that, thank you Vince.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in a separate workspace and the only reasonable answer is that **you have only one feature in your layer.** Your code should iterate through all the items found by the cursor as written.

Assuming this is not the exact code, check that there is no `where_clause` argument on the `SearchCursor`. Even if there are no layer selections, the cursor allows selecting only certain records. It is a *search* cursor, after all.

Some comments on the code in general, some mentioned elsewhere:

- Please change your cursor declaration to `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, fields) as cursor1:` with all the code that uses the cursor indented. This will release the cursor resource (and any GDB locks) after completion.
- `else: continue` is completely redundant and it may be removed entirely in both instances.
- The condition `if (a != None and a != 0 and a!= 0.0):` may be simply rewritten as `if a:`.
- Please rename your dictionary, `dict` is a reserved keyword and Python convention is to not reuse keywords.
- You may be better served using `bool` values as your indicators instead of `0` and `1` `int` values, unless these *must* map to ArcGIS domains.
- If the field you are selecting and parsing is a string, as it looks like it may be, you may be able to replace your inner `for` loops:

```py
for row1 in cursor1:
  dict[row1[-1]] = [bool(row1[:12].lstrip()), bool(row1[12:-1].lstrip())]
```

It does also seem as if you're setting the `OBJECTID` to an array value (which is not valid), but I don't recognize this pattern so perhaps there's something else going on here.

Comment: Thank you, Stephan. The comments were really useful for making my script more efficient. 

To "you have only one feature in your layer.", there were more than that, and I used GetCount to make sure beforehand. I suspect it is a bug after running through the dataset multiple times. FYI, restarting did not work either :D

Comment: @user206005 have you looked at the `SearchCursor` constructor to make sure there was no where clause on there that may be limiting you to one feature? And... I don't imagine restarting would help this situation. :-)